# How to use hex(x ' ' ) inside of a sql statement with python execute?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am working in Python/Django with a MySQL Db. This sql query works fine in my Workbench

```
SELECT * FROM frontend_appliance_sensor_reading 
WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) FROM frontend_appliance_sensor_reading WHERE sensor_id = hex(x'28E86479972003D2') AND
appliance_id = 185)
```

I am returning the latest record for a sensor. The hex string is the sensor ID that I need to pass in as a variable in python.

Here is my python function that would return this object

```
def get_last_sensor_reading(appliance_id, sensor_id):
    dw_conn = connection
    dw_cur = dw_conn.cursor()

    appliance_id_lookup = appliance_id
    dw_cur.execute('''
           SELECT * FROM frontend_appliance_sensor_reading as sr 
           WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) FROM frontend_appliance_sensor_reading WHERE sensor_id = hex(x{sensor_id_lookup}) AND
           appliance_id = {appliance_id_lookup})
        '''.format(appliance_id_lookup=appliance_id_lookup, sensor_id_lookup = str(sensor_id)))
    values = dw_cur.fetchall()

    dw_cur.close()
    dw_conn.close()
    print values
```

However it seems to concat the x with the variable like this:
(1054, "Unknown column 'x9720032F0100DE86' in 'where clause'")

I have tried various string combinations to get it to execute correctly with no luck. What am I missing? Does the x actually get interpreted as a str? Or should I be converting it to something else prior?

Also, I cannot not use Django's ORM for this as the sensor id is stored in a BinaryField as BLOB data. You cannot filter by BLOB data in Django. This is the reason I am using a sql command instead of just doing SensorReading.objects.filter(sensor_id = sensor).latest('id)

Comment: Why don't you try setting a variable to the string of the fully constructed query and printing it out. Then you can test what is actually being executed.

Comment: Ok I did that, thank you. It is constructing it just as it seems to in sql: SELECT* FROM frontend_appliance_sensor_reading WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) FROM f                                                                                                                                                             rontend_appliance_sensor_reading WHERE sensor_id = hex(x9720032F0100DE86) AND ap                                                                                                                                                             pliance_id =185)

Comment: Does copying that exact string into the MySQL prompt work?

Comment: Comparing SQLs, this `hex(x'28E86479972003D2')` and this `hex(x9720032F0100DE86)`, single quotes are missing in the second case.

Comment: Maybe you need in `HEX(0x28E86479972003D2)`? in code - `.. hex(0x{sensor_id_lookup}) ..`. or, backward, `UNHEX('28E86479972003D2')`?

Comment: shn - No, i need the single quotes as Borut said. Have tried to format as so, with no luck yet. Will maybe try Akina's way, haven't tried that yet

Comment: Akina - your solution worked, not really sure why but using 0x instead works